comparing transfer learning styles for creating model
i would like  to  ask question about one thing : for instance common form for  transfer learning is this :
base_model = VGG19(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', pooling="avg", include_top=False)
x = Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="output")(base_model.output)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
print(model.summary())

i am  always using a simplest  form, therefore  i will use folloiwng form :
base_model =VGG19(include_top=False,input_shape=(224,224,3))
model =Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Flatten())
print(model.summary())

i would like to  ask if these forms are equivalent? i am not talking about classification layer, from convolution to classification layer, more  specifily pooling="avg" and flatten both should be used right?

No, you either use GlobalPooling (Avg - Max) or Flatten layer in order to convert 4D output into 2D from the base model.

so in my model i use flatten, so  it can be used right yes?

Yes you can include 'flatten layer'.The first method uses average pooling
This results in a 2D tensor representing the global average features.
The second method likely defaults to max pooling, producing a 4D
tensor at final layer,you used flatten which converts it to 2D.The first
method is functional api and another one is sequential api.Generally we
prefer functional api due to follow reasons.
While the Functional API offers more flexibility for complex models with
multiple inputs and outputs, the Sequential API is simpler for models with a
linear stack of layers.
